# Laravel migration dropColumn drop the wrong column

Tags: php, laravel, model, migration, rollback

I've a very weird issue i cannot explain. This make me worrying a lot because the project i'm working on is online and I might update the database columns sometimes.

```
// Migration file

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class ChangeUserProfilesTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {

        Schema::table('user_profiles', function($table)
        {

            // Keys
            $table->datetime('status_updated_at')->nullable();

        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {

        Schema::table('user_profiles', function($table)
        {

            // Columns to remove
            $table->dropColumn('status_updated_at');

        });

    }

}
```

Now I migrate, everything works well i checked and my table is the good one

```
html(master)$ php artisan migrate
Migrated: 2015_03_19_111236_change_user_profiles_table
```

Here's a part of my MySQL table

[image: some columns everything is normal]

Now I rollback, as simple as it sounds.

```
 html(master)$ php artisan migrate:rollback
 Rolled back: 2015_03_19_111236_change_user_profiles_table
```

And now I just look at my table and it gets freaky

[image: my column vanished]

Yes, the `status` column vanished for no reason. And there's still the one that was supposed to be removed. I tried 10 times it just doesn't work ... I cannot even `migrate` anymore because

```
   [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
   SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'status_
   updated_at' (SQL: alter table `user_profiles` add `status_updated_at` datet
   ime null)
```

Someone has an idea about it ? If it's an issue, it's a BIG one because migrations are really sensitive stuff within a project ... I don't really trust Laravel anymore and I wonder how I'll do with the production side.

**EDIT : To find a solution here are all the migrations linked with this table (but it shouldn't be called anyway ...)

I'm using Laravel 4.2**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUserProfilesTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_profiles', function($table)
        {

            // Keys
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('box_id')->unsigned()->nullable();

            $table->string('stripe_customer');

            $table->string('contract_id');

            // Indexes
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('box_id')->references('id')->on('boxes')->onDelete('cascade');

            // Timestamps
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {

        Schema::table('user_profiles', function(Blueprint $table)
        {

            $table->dropForeign('user_profiles_user_id_foreign');
            $table->dropForeign('user_profiles_box_id_foreign');

        });

        Schema::dropIfExists('user_profiles');

    }


}
```

And later

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class ChangeUserProfilesTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('user_profiles', function($table)
        {

            // Keys
            $table->enum('status', array('not-subscribed', 'in-progress', 'subscribed', 'expired'));

        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {

        Schema::table('user_profiles', function(Blueprint $table)
        {

            // Columns to remove
            $table->dropColumn('status');

        });


    }

}
```

Comment: Are there any constraints? Foreign key constraint? Which version of laravel are you using? Have you updated with composer so you've the latest bug fixes?

Comment: There are some constraints but it shouldn't change anything about `status` and `status_updated_at` isn't it ? It's `Laravel 4.2` and this version of composer is around `5 months old` (the beginning of the project) and i'm very afraid to update it on my server ...

Comment: Are you sure you don't have two classes that are named the same ? From what I see ```ChangeUserProfilesTable``` is used for both of your migrations. So it appears that the actual migration that is called on ```rollback``` is the one with ```status``` field being created. Try to use ```dd``` in this migration ```rollback``` method and check if this is it. By the way you should get an error about ```ChangeUserProfilesTable ``` being ambigious. If you did not then maybe your configuration is supressing this message.

Comment: If the autoload isn't finding the class he is trying to rollback a other version of the table. Probably doing ```comoser dump-autoload``` can help you in combination with the comment above? https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7667

Comment: It is quite an interesting behaviour. But ```composer dump-autoload``` should detect that you have two classes in the same namespace with same name and let you know about it. Anyway in the future I'd advice a bit more descriptive names for your migrations like ```update_user_profiles_table_add_status_column``` or so. This way you are pretty much sure your migration name won't collide with any other.

Comment: You were right, a `composer dump-autoload` let me know i had a problem with my classe names, i changed the names specifying some columns and it works fine now ! Thank you guys for your help really ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact I had the same name of classe in some migrations put composer in trouble. A `composer dump-autoload` allowed me to see it.

For instance :

```
 Generating autoload files
 Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "ChangeBoxQuestionsTable" was found in both      "/Users/Loschcode/Dropbox/htdocs/projets/bordeaux_in_box_lo/html/app/database/migrations/2015_03_12_183836_change_box_questions_table.php" and "/Users/Loschcode/Dropbox/htdocs/projets/bordeaux_in_box_lo/html/app/database/migrations/2015_03_19_040137_change_box_questions_table.php", the first will be used.
```

So I changed manually my files / classes names and also in the database `migrations` table too. Now it works fine ;)